# How to not only open a HTML file from python CGI script but also pass data like strings and JSON files to HTML script?

Tags: html, json, python-3.x, cgi

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a while without using a framework (I can make this work with Flask for example) but I haven't found anything as of yet. I have two html scripts and a python cgi script. In essence I have the first html file wherein the user enters a string that I read into my python cgi script which in turn does a number of things to finally give me a bunch of strings and json file that I need to pass to another html file and be able to read them there as well.

So far the first half works, and I can open the second html with a redirect which is not elegant but nothing else has worked with the following code:

```
#!/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin//python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
cgitb.enable()

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
protein_name = form.getvalue('protein_name')
####### function search_results takes in protein_name and gives me the data ###
####### I need to pass to the html file: results.html #########################


if ((search_results(protein_name)!="No protein entered")&(search_results(protein_name)!="No results found")):

    all_vars = search_results(protein_name)
    ##### all_vars is a tuple of strings like gene_name, json files and integers
    print("Content-type: text/html","\n\n")
    print ('''
  <head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://localhost/results.html'" /></head>    
''')
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably discovered, your current technique issues a redirect to 'results.html', but otherwise discards any results. I don't know exactly what your goals are, but one approach would be to treat 'results.html' as a simple template. Your script will populate it and return it in response to each request. In the example below, 'results.html' can contain arbitrary HTML, along with the line '##RESULTS##', which will be replaced with your output.

```
#!/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

def process_results(results):
    if results=='No protein entered' or results=='No results found':
        return results
    # else do something with results, e.g., format into an HTML table
    buf = '<table>\n'
    for result in results:
        buf += f'<tr><td>{cgi.escape(str(result))}</td></tr>\n'
    buf += '</table>\n'
    return buf

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
protein_name = form.getvalue('protein_name')
results = search_results(protein_name)

print("Content-type: text/html\n")
with open('results.html') as template:
    for line in (x.rstrip() for x in template):
        if line == '##RESULTS##':
            print(process_results(results))
        else:
            print(line)
```

Good luck.